# How do I report or edit biased tag descriptions?

Tags: support, tag

As I do not got enough points, I cannot edit any description of a tag. I cannot report it for being "bad" either.

I've noticed that the tag [bidah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bidah) has a very one faced description and definition which is against Stack Exchange's guidelines of how to create tags:

> **What should I write in the tag wiki?**
>
> - Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized.

https://islam.stackexchange.com/tags/bidah/info

In this case, the concept is not defined in a way that is mentioned in the guideliness, it's rather very obscure.

**How do I report or edit tags that are defined (with one face definitions)?**

Comment: inre the [tag:Bidah] tag itself (which details i kept out of my answer proper to keep it generic) I have at least removed the Truth assertions; tag wikis are definitely not the place for pushing what is or is not "haram". The tag wiki itself is still rather blah and could definitely use improvement, and I can't really judge on the definition itself (note: even if the definition is simplistic or incomplete, as long as it is consistent with how the tag is *used* (and likely to *be* used) on the site it's probably not a problem)

Comment: I saw your edit. As you said, it could be improved, but it's much better than the last description. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It takes [1500 reputation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) to vote to approve or reject an edit to a tag wiki — or [4000 reputation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) to apply one immediately — but anyone can *suggest* one just by clicking the Edit Tag Info button:

[image]

This will put your edit into the [Suggested Edits Review Queue](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20754), where it can be reviewed and accepted (or rejected, as the case may be) by anybody who *does* have sufficient reputation to do so.

If you want to know if your suggestion is still pending, or if/when it was ultimately accepted or rejected (including the voting breakdown which would explain *why*), you can check in your profile under the Activity→All Actions→Suggestions tab:

[image]

If you've already made the suggestion and had it rejected — or if it seems to be taking an unusually long time to get processed — you can then bring it up on meta to get more focus on it: Explain as best you can *what* your suggested edit was and *why* it was an improvement on what was already there, and open the discussion to the community to decide how best to handle it; be willing to accept any input the community has to offer to further improve your own edit-attempt. Any future attempts to push the edit into the queue can then link to the relevant meta discussion in the revision comment.

Unless something is *blatantly* inappropriate (e.g. offensive language, spam) I see little need to *report* a problematic tag-wiki entry before all the above steps have been taken: If every reasonable attempt to apply the edit yourself and/or discuss the issue with the community has failed, then direct moderator intervention may be needed. In such cases, you can simply raise a flag "In need of moderator intervention" on the meta discussion itself with a detailed explanation of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually made an edit a while ago on the tag. But I asked this question because I noticed that the edit I made was removed (if it isn't just hidden) without any kind of response or reply.

Comment: @Kilise Yeah, I saw that; it went through the queue and got rejected by 2:1 vote. I can only speculate as to *why*, but bringing it up in its own meta discussion would probably help (may or may not get an actual explanation from the people who rejected it, but at least would help improve it for a second try)

Comment: You can see your own suggested-edits history on your profile (Activity>All Actions>Suggestions), which links to the actual voting outcome in the queue.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the voting now. It looks like it was rejected of subjective reasons. Your edit is OK, so I can leave it for now. But I think this is something to us a community to think about how to handle in a better way. As you said it might help to bring it up in the meta discussion.